# Using Coroutine in Unity

Tags: c#, android, arrays, unity-game-engine

Am working on Unity and here is what I want to do: play the *animationType* in a time difference of 10sec. I want the code to loop through the animations and play them each for 10seconds. The code runs without errors, except the result is not what I expected it to be. It plays the first animation,*Boxing*, for 10 seconds and just when it's about to play the *Backflip* animation, it starts to do some weird thing to the character. That's where is goes wrong.

Here is my code:

```
public class BeBot_Controller : MonoBehaviour
{    

    Animator anim;
    string animationType;
    string[] split;
    int arrayLength;

    void Start()
    {
        //AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass("yenettaapp.my_bebot_plugin.My_BeBot_Plugin");
        //animationType = pluginClass.CallStatic<string>("getMessage");
        animationType="Null,Boxing,Backflip";
        split = animationType.Split(',');
        anim = gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Animator> ();
        arrayLength = split.Length;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (arrayLength > 1){
            StartCoroutine ("LoopThroughAnimation");
        }
    }

    IEnumerator LoopThroughAnimation()
    {
        for (int i = 1 ; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            animationType = split [i];
            //anim.SetInteger ("AnimPar", 0);
            anim.Play (animationType);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (10);
        }
    }
}
```

So what did I do wrong here ? Is there any other way I can solve this problem ?

Comment: You need to post the complete code in that class. This is not enough to help you.

Comment: Coroutine inside Loop inside Update function, must be troublesome. However, The for loop's closing bracket is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your animation loop only needs to be called once, simply move `StartCoroutine()` to `Start()` and remove the `Update()` stuff:

```
public class BeBot_Controller  : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator anim;
    private string animationType;
    private string[] split;
    private int arrayLength;

    void Start ()
    {
        //AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass("yenettaapp.my_bebot_plugin.My_BeBot_Plugin");
        //animationType = pluginClass.CallStatic<string>("getMessage");
        animationType = "Null,Boxing,Backflip";
        split = animationType.Split(',');
        anim = gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();
        arrayLength = split.Length;

        // Call here
        StartCoroutine(LoopThroughAnimation());
    }

    IEnumerator LoopThroughAnimation ()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < arrayLength; i++)
        {
            animationType = split[i];
            Debug.Log(animationType);

            //anim.SetInteger ("AnimPar", 0);
            anim.Play(animationType);

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works just fine. But what do we need the Update method for ??

Comment: @NathanDamtew  `Update` is for *per-frame* behaviour. See [Update And FixedUpdate](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/update-and-fixedupdate) :)

Comment: Yes it does. Thank You @Lece